# Connection Error for Apache Ignite on Azure Kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, .net-core, ignite

I am new to Ignite and Kubernetes.
I try to move our on-premises solution to Microsoft Cloud. The first step is moving to Apache Ignite to Azure Kubernetes.

I follow instructions ([Apache Ignite Instructions](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/microsoft-azure-deployment)) and set up the ignite app on Azure Kubernetes. When I control the services from the control panel, it's running and the services seem like the below image.

[Please see the ignite service image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqS5X.png)

But finally, I try to create sample data on Ignite I am getting error.

I try to connect like this from power shell:

```
PS az login     
PS C:\apache-ignite-2.8.0-bin\bin> ./sqlline.bat --verbose=true -u jdbc:ignite:thin://{MyExternalIP}:10800
```

After this, I get this message from power shell

> issuing: !connect jdbc:ignite:thin://{MyExternalIP}:10800 '' ''
>   org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver Connecting to
>   jdbc:ignite:thin://{MyExternalIP}:10800 Connected to: Apache Ignite
>   (version 2.6.0#20180710-sha1:669feacc) Driver: Apache Ignite Thin JDBC
>   Driver (version 2.8.0#20200226-sha1:341b01df) Autocommit status: true
>   Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ sqlline version
>   1.3.0 0: jdbc:ignite:thin://{MyExternalIP}:10800>

And finally, I run the latest command to test from instructions

```
!run ../examples/sql/world.sql
```

Here is the error message for this command.

> Error: Statement is closed. (state=,code=0) java.sql.SQLException:
>   Statement is closed.
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.ensureNotClosed(JdbcThinStatement.java:934)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.getWarnings(JdbcThinStatement.java:538)
>           at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:849)
>           at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:733)
>           at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:795)
>           at sqlline.SqlLine.runCommands(SqlLine.java:1706)
>           at sqlline.Commands.run(Commands.java:1317)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at sqlline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:38)
>           at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:791)
>           at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:668)
>           at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:373)
>           at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:265) Aborting command set because "force" is false and command failed: "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
>   Country;"

[The All power shell is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37HDm.png)

I have no idea what is wrong?

Comment: please read the [tag:apache] tag description and edit your question to make it relevant to the topics mentioned there before you add the tag _again_.

Comment: I can see that you have Ignite 2.6 but driver version is 2.8. Have you tried using the same version of both? Any exceptions on server-side?

Comment: @alamar thanks for the tip. I download the Ignite 2.6.0 and it worked.

Comment: @alamar You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you have Ignite 2.6 but driver version is 2.8. Have you tried using the same version of both? We suppose that the driver may be compatible between versions, but it is not recommended setup.